# Jquery mobile phonegap disable submit button if no network

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

Im trying to disable my submit buttons on my jquery mobile app. Ive tried for days to get it to work. the buttons just will not enable or disable. this is one of many scripts I have tried enter

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';


        if(networkState==Connection.UNKNOWN || networkState==Connection.NONE) {
            $('[type="submit"]').button('disable');
            $('[type="submit"]').button('refresh');

        } else {
            $('[type="submit"]').button('enable');
            $('[type="submit"]').button('refresh');


        }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

doesn't it should be like this:

```
if(networkState==states.Connection.UNKNOWN || networkState==states.Connection.NONE) {
   //........... your code stuff..............//
}
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to mention about the code inside the if clause. `.button(...)` does not make sense to me unless it's a custom fn. If hunty is trying to enable/disable the button it would be better to use `.prop("disabled", true)` and so on. What do you think?

Comment: tried that, did not work. I know the button function works because I ran a script on its own to just disable it to see if it worked. just noticed on eclipse log it says uncaught error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
mybutton.disabled = true
```